# How to use network Service Discovery in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to use Network Service Discovery in Windows Phone 8 Apps to Register my Servce on the Network so that I can identify other devices on the local network that support the services My app requests.
Is there any Library that is avaliable for windows phone 8

Comment: Have you used StreamSocket class?

Comment: yes I have used StreamSocket. But how to know the Ip Address of Another Device in Which I want to connect???

Comment: for that I have found Mono.Zeroconf library. It has methods that is Used to Register our service, but this is not working for windows phone8. It gives error when i Try to include that package using Nuget...